# Losing first few seconds of audio

Tags: audio, raspbian-buster, audio-playback, pulseaudio

So on my Raspberry pi when I play audio through the headphone jack, the first few seconds of sound are lost. However, I if I immediately play the sound again, the audio works fine from the very beginning of the sample. The end of period when I can start the second sample and have the audio work properly is signaled by a slight pop from the speakers. I'm using pulseaudio on RP-3

Searching online has led me to the options of disabling idling of sinks and constantly playing silent sound (using `play -n` from sox) to keep the sink running. Neither has any effect on the issue.

I'm playing the sound using `paplay sound.wav`.

Output of `pactl list short sinks`:

```
0       alsa_output.platform-soc_audio.analog-mono      module-alsa-card.c      s16le 1ch 48000Hz     RUNNING
```

Why is the PI losing the first few seconds of audio and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think it’s a bug in Buster - I did not have this in Stretch and it’s gone with an I2S DAC I’ve added.

Comment: @Andyroo forgive me, but could clarify what an I2C DAC is?

Comment: Sorry typing error - I meant and I2S DAC.  These are add on cards that use the I2S bus built into the Pi and provides a digital to analogue converter output for speakers or headphones - they start from around £15 upwards https://volumio.org/raspberry-pi-i2s-dac-sounds-so-good/

Comment: Just wondering whether anyone else had any thoughts on this? Having the same issue, and would like to avoid adding a further component in the form of a DAC.

Answer (score 0):

You should unload the pulse audio module **module-suspend-on-idle**.

To do that create a file under </etc/pulse/default.pa.d/disable-idle.pa> containing `unload-module module-suspend-on-idle`.

To do that you can use the following command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "unload-module module-suspend-on-idle" > /etc/pulse/default.pa.d/disable-idle.pa'
```

Then restart pulseaudio with the commands:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

After that this problem should go away for good.